# Selecting substring inside string in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm totally new in shell scripting and trying to extract substring inside the string that user input. I have file `a.txt` that contains:

```
abc.com
div.abc.com
```

now if the user give input `www.abc.com` then I want to select `abc.com` from that file and put `abc.com` into a variable.
and if the user gives input `prod.div.abc.com` then I want to select `div.abc.com` from that file and put `div.abc.com` into a variable.

I try to use:

```
while read line; do
  bc=$(echo $fq | grep -P '^('$line'!?)')
  if [[ $fq =~ $bc ]]
        then
        echo $line
  fi
done <a.txt
```

Seems the output is far from my expectation.

Comment: Where do you set `$fq`?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you provide additional input patterns and expected output patterns?

Comment: @RafkiAltoberi : On each iteration of the loop, `line` is set to one line of the file `a.txt`. Then you feed an empty string (`echo $fq`) into `grep`, which of course doesn't match your regexp. This sets `bc` therefore to an empty string too. Finally, you do a `$fq =~ $bc`, which should succeed, as both variables are empty. Hence in total, I would expect your program to basically print the content of `a.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash4's associative array, it is more efficient to store your domains file `a.txt` as an associative array keys (or dictionary keys).

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -r domain_names_file='a.txt'

# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # Safe assignment of associative array keys
declare -rA domain_keys="($(
  # Transforms the domain_names lines from the file into associative array keys
  # of domain names while stripping-out the trailing dot if any.
  # Allows fast checking a domain name.
  sed <"$domain_names_file" 's/\.$//' | xargs -l1 printf '[%q]= '
))"

# Matches argument against domain keys
# @Globals:
# domain_keys: The associative array containing
#   dictionary keys of domains to match against
# @Args:
# 1: The domainks to check
# @Output:
# >&1: Matching domain
# @Return
# false if no matching domain found
match_domain() {
  # Strip trailing dot of FQDN if any
  local -- domain="${1%.}"
  while [[ $domain =~ [^.]+\.?(.*) ]]; do
    if [[ "${domain_keys[$domain]+isset}" ]]; then
      echo "$domain"
      return
    fi
    # RegEx Match capture group 1 contains the domain name stripped of
    # its leading sub-domain if any. So lets continue with it...
    domain="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  done
  # No match found, returns false
  false
}

while read -r -p 'Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): ' reply; do
  # Get domain match
  if matched_domain="$(match_domain "$reply")"; then
    printf 'Found domain: %q\n' "$matched_domain"
  else
    printf 'No domain match for %q\n' "${reply%.}"
  fi
done

echo
```

#### Lets test it

Populate `a.txt`:

```sh
cat >a.txt <<EOF
example.com
div.example.com.
localhost
localhost.localdomain
EOF
```

Run the script use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to stop:

```
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): www.example.com.
Found domain: example.com
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit):  example.com
Found domain: example.com
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): sub.div.example.com
Found domain: div.example.com
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): sub2.sub1.div.example.com
Found domain: div.example.com
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): localhost.
Found domain: localhost
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): localhost.localdomain.
Found domain: localhost.localdomain
Enter domain name to check (or CTRL+D to quit): does.not.exist
No domain match for does.not.exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try capturing the input from the user using `read` and then use grep to search for the match.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=a.txt

read -rp 'Enter input ' input

if var=$(grep -x "${input#*.}" "$file") || var=$(grep -x "$input" "$file"); then
  echo "$var"
else
  echo "$input not found in $file" >&2
fi
```

- This assumes that your file has one entry per-line.
- If there is a match it will be in the `"$var"`
- Both input can have the leading `prod.` and `www.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `read` is intended to get user input, while `a.txt` has the list of patterns to match:

```
while read line; do
  if match=$(printf %s "$line" | grep -F -o -f a.txt) ; then
    var="$match"
    printf "match is %s\n" "$match"
  fi
done
```

The options to `grep` are:

- `-F` — match fixed strings
- `-o` — print only matched portion
- `-f a.txt` — read patterns (fixed strings) from file `a.txt`